# Problems with IDIV Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

CX is equal to 14
AX is equal to 16

```
IDIV CX
```

But somewhy in AL there is 37.
There is no mistakes or errors before that line.
Where I've made a mistake?
Thank you!
p.s. writting on Emu8086

Comment: Try doing an `xor dx, dx` before the div.

Comment: You want `cwd` before 16-bit `idiv` (signed division).  Zero-extension (of ax into dx:ax) would give wrong results for negative divisors or dividends.  See also [IDIV operation in assembly (understanding)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25489192) / [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416593)

Answer (score 2):

`IDIV CX` divides the 32-bit value `DX:AX` by `CX`, and stores the quotient in `AX` and the remainder in `DX`.

Therefore the value of `DX` prior to the `IDIV` instruction matters, and you should either sign-extend `AX` into `DX` using the `CWD` instruction (before `IDIV`), or clear `DX` using e.g. `XOR DX,DX` (before `DIV`).