# IDIV operation in assembly (understanding)

Tags: assembly, x86

when I have the the operation

```
IDIV ecx
```

in assembly, then i have read that the that the value in edx:eax is divided by the operand ecx. I also know that the quotient is stored in eax and the remainder in edx.

so but what exactly is the value in edx:eax ??

Can someone explain it to me?

edit: i also did not understand the reason of "cdq" operation which come always before the IDIV operation although I have read some pages about that.

Comment: you should probably explain that you're talking about x86 ASM. "assembler" is a generic term, and not specific to any cpu/instruction set.

Comment: Plus, your answer is already documented: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Added_with_80386

Comment: R = X/Y.   The numerator X of the division is in edx:eax and the denominator Y is in ECX.  If you want to divide two numbers you have to supply those two numbers not just one of them.  So you supply the numerator in edx:eax and denominator in ecx and do the division and get a result.

Answer (score 5):

> i have read that the that the value in edx:eax is divided by the operand ... but what exactly is the value in edx:eax ?

`EDX:EAX` in this context means the 64-bit value formed by the registers `EDX` and `EAX`, where `EDX` is interpreted as containing the most significant bits, and `EAX` the least significant bits.

`CDQ` converts the doubleword in `EAX` into a quadword in `EDX:EAX` by sign-extending `EAX` into `EDX` (i.e. each bit of `EDX` is filled with the most significant bit of `EAX`). For example, if `EAX` contained `0x7FFFFFFF` you'd get `0` in `EDX`, since the most significant bit of `EAX` is clear. But if you had `EAX = 0x80000000` you'd get `EDX = 0xFFFFFFFF` since the most significant bit of `EAX` is set.
The point of `CDQ` is to set up `EDX` prior to a division by a 32-bit operand, since the dividend is `EDX:EAX`.

Answer (score 1):

What is it? It's the value you put there because you want to divide it...

The CDQ instruction takes a 32-bit value in EAX and converts it into a 64-bit value in EDX:EAX (by copying the sign bit of EAX into every bit of EDX). You use it if (as is usual) the value you want to divide is 32-bit to begin with.