# Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-division

I noticed when EDX contains some random default value like 00401000, and I then use a DIV instruction like this:

```
mov eax,10
mov ebx,5
div ebx
```

it causes an INTEGER OVERFLOW ERROR. However, if I set `edx` to 0 and do the same thing it works. I believed that using `div` would result in the quotient overwriting `eax` and the remainder overwriting `edx`.

Getting this INTEGER OVERFLOW ERROR really confuses me.

Comment: That's just how the instruction is defined/implemented - for a 32-bit operand, it divides the 64-bit value in edx:eax with the 32-bit operand value.

Comment: you are dividing a 64 bit number by a 32 bit number, you have to set all 64 bits before you start otherwise your result will make no sense.

Comment: That link is from the [FAQ section of the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  There's a ton of good stuff there for people dealing with asm.

Comment: You would be very well served to look at an instruction reference before using an unfamiliar opcode. :)

Comment: Related: 8-bit operand size is a special case: `div bl` (16b / 8b => 8b), using AX (not DL:AL). [8086 assembly on DOSBox: Bug with idiv instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43575674)

Comment: A possible canonical duplicate (for other questions, not this) for 8-bit `div` without zeroing AH [Assembly Divide by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38788694)

Comment: In what context does it cause "INTEGER OVERFLOW ERROR"? What CPU, external hardware, system, etc.?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### What to do

For 32-bit / 32-bit => 32-bit division: zero- or sign-extend the 32-bit dividend from EAX into 64-bit EDX:EAX.
For 16-bit, AX into DX:AX with `cwd` or xor-zeroing.

- unsigned: `XOR EDX,EDX` then `DIV divisor`
- signed: `CDQ` then `IDIV divisor`

See also [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464879/when-and-why-do-we-sign-extend-and-use-cdq-with-mul-div)

---

#### Why (TL;DR)

For [`DIV`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html), the registers `EDX` and `EAX` form one single 64 bit value (often shown as `EDX:EAX`), which is then divided, in this case, by `EBX`.

So if `EAX` = `10` or hex `A` and `EDX` is, say `20` or hex `14`, then together they form the 64 bit value hex `14 0000 000A` or decimal `85899345930`. If this is divided by `5`, the result is `17179869186` or hex
 
`4 0000 0002`, **which is a value that does not fit in 32 bits**.

**That is why you get an integer overflow.**

If, however, `EDX` were only `1`, you would divide hex `1 0000 000A` by `5`, which results in hex
 `3333 3335`. That is not the value you wanted, but it does not cause an integer overflow.

To really divide 32 bit register `EAX` by another 32 bit register, take care that the top of the 64 bit value formed by `EDX:EAX` is `0`.

So, **before** a single division, you should *generally* set `EDX` to `0`.

(Or for signed division, `cdq` to sign extend `EAX` into `EDX:EAX` before `idiv`)

---

But `EDX` does not have always have to be `0`. It can just not be that big that the result causes an overflow.

One example from my `BigInteger` code:

After a division with `DIV`, the quotient is in `EAX` and the remainder is in `EDX`. To divide something like a `BigInteger`, which consists of an array of many `DWORDS`, by `10` (for instance to convert the value to a decimal string), you do something like the following:

```
    ; ECX contains number of "limbs" (DWORDs) to divide by 10
    XOR     EDX,EDX      ; before start of loop, set EDX to 0
    MOV     EBX,10
    LEA     ESI,[EDI + 4*ECX - 4] ; now points to top element of array
@DivLoop:
    MOV     EAX,[ESI]
    DIV     EBX          ; divide EDX:EAX by EBX. After that,
                         ; quotient in EAX, remainder in EDX
    MOV     [ESI],EAX
    SUB     ESI,4        ; remainder in EDX is re-used as top DWORD... 
    DEC     ECX          ; ... for the next iteration, and is NOT set to 0.
    JNE     @DivLoop
```

After that loop, the value represented by the entire array (i.e. by the `BigInteger`) is divided by `10`, and `EDX` contains the remainder of that division.

*FWIW, in the assembler I use (Delphi's built-in assembler), labels starting with `@` are local to the function, i.e. they don't interfere with equally named labels in other functions.*

Comment: This might be a better canonical answer to the "why did my broken divide code not work"  FAQ than the duplicate I marked.  I made an edit to fix a syntax error, but there's another bug: `ESI` holds a pointer in your loop, so `JNE @DivLoop` won't exit the loop until you've gone down the entire address space to `ESI = (int*)4`.  Maybe you meant to use a `dec ecx`, or a `cmp`?

Comment: FWIW, @PeterCordes: in my assembler, both `DIV EAX,EBX` and `DIV EBX`are allowed. But since in one version, `DIV EBX` generated bad code, but `DIV EAX,EBX` didn't, I always use the latter.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I didn't copy this verbatim (my code uses unrolled loops  and is far more complicated). I guess I forgot something. I'll amend.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was wondering how that `div eax, ebx` got in there in an example based on working code!  (and yes, I could tell it must not have been copy/pasted verbatim).  While you're at it, I'd suggest a comment to point out that it's intentional that you don't zero `EDX` inside the loop; that the remainder from the previous division is the upper half of the input to the next limb.  (That is intentional, right?  That seems sensible for BigInteger)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think my comment at the end of the loop alread explains this (i.e. that EDX is not zeroed out).

Comment: Oh, yes.  I was expecting that comment to say something about the looping itself, so didn't read it.  BTW, I updated the x86 tag wiki to point here.  I'm going to leave this marked as a duplicate for now, though, since I think the link to my answer on the other question is also potentially useful.  Thanks for taking the time to write a nice answer to one of these bad questions so we can just link instead of retyping stuff in comments on new dups :)

Answer (score 2):

The DIV instruction divides EDX:EAX by the r/m32 that follows the DIV instruction. So, if you fail to set EDX to zero, the value you are using becomes extremely large.

Trust that helps