# Assembly Divide by zero

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am trying to write code for a program to calculate the average of an array but I get the divide by zero error, I googled the error and it seems that it is a divide overflow but I didn't understand what should I do in my program to work. Here is my code:

```
`DATA SEGMENT
msg1 db 0dh,0ah,"Please enter the length of the array: $"
msg2 db 0ah,0ah,"Enter number: $"
msg3 db 0dh,0ah,"Array average is: $"
val db ?

DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA

START:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

mov dx,offset msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h

mov bl,al
mov cl,al
MOV AL,00
MOV VAL,AL
lbl1:
mov dx,offset msg2
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h

add al, val
mov val,al
loop lbl1

lbl2:
mov dx,offset msg3
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov al, val

div bl
add ax,3030h
mov dx,ax
mov ah,02h
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

Code ends
end Start
CODE ENDS`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div bl` divides `ax` by `bl` and stores the quotient in `al`, and the remainder in `ah`. The quotient must be in the range 0x00..0xFF, or you'll get a division overflow.

The last thing you set `ah` to before the division is 9. Since `ah` is the most significant part of `ax` that means `ax` will have the value 0x9XY (where XY are any hexadecimal digits) when you do the division. So to get a quotient that's <=0xFF you would have to divide by at least 10.

The solution is to clear `ah` before the division (`xor ah,ah` or `mov ah,0`).

Comment: I tried but still no success. Like this?                                                                           mov al, val                             
xor ah,ah
div bx

Comment: @user3848412 Now you're doing `div bx` instead of `div bl`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: In your question you use `div bl`, not `div bx`. The answer depends on the exact variant of `div` that is used.

Comment: Yeah, it works now, thank you for the answer and the explanation, I understood now.

Comment: @user3848412: See also [the canonical answer about zeroing the `[e/r]dx` before `div`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416593/why-should-edx-be-0-before-i-use-div-opcode/38416896#38416896), linked from the x86 [tag wiki's FAQ section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)