# Volume of cone not returning correct value

Tags: math, assembly, x86, irvine32

My code assembles correctly, however it is not returning the volume of a cone. I tried a few other ways to get it to give me the volume of a cone, and it doesn't give me the correct answer. Is there something I am missing?

Edit: I fixed my code to output a number, however its not giving me the right number.

This is the formula I am using for this code:
V= (22)(r)(r)(h)/21

```
diviser         DWORD       21
height          WORD        0
radius          BYTE        0                                           ;*** Declare an unsigned, integer variable for the value
product         WORD        0
askRadius       BYTE        "What is the radius?", 0ah, 0dh, 0              ;*** Declare the prompt and message parts
askHeight       BYTE        "What is the height? ", 0
volumeOutput    BYTE        "The volume of the cone is:  ", 0   
lineBreak       BYTE        " ",0dh, 0ah, 0

.code
main PROC

mov ebx, diviser                         ;Initializes the diviser

mov edx,OFFSET askRadius                 ;Asks for Radius
call WriteString
call ReadDec
mov radius, al                           ;moves radius into al (8-bit)
mul radius                               ;Multiplies radius * radius(16-bit)

mov edx,OFFSET askHeight                 ;asks for Height
call writestring
call ReadDec
mov height, dx                           ;moves height into AX
mov WORD PTR product, ax                 ;convert 16-bit into 32-bit
mov WORD PTR product+2, dx               ;converts 16-bit into 32-bit
mul eax                                  ;multiplies by 22
mov edx, 22                              
mul edx
div ebx                                  ;divides by 21

mov edx, OFFSET volumeOutput             
call WriteString
call WriteDec
call WaitMsg
exit
```

main ENDP
END main

Comment: Please be more specific than "its not giving me the right number." Which number did you expect and which did you actually get? Also, in which environment are you running this--i.e. what exactly are the routines `WriteString`, `ReadDec`, `WriteDec`, and `WaitMsg`? Note that the capitalization of `WriteString` varies in your code.

Comment: Many errors in there. For example, the result of `mul radius` is discarded (overwritten by the height). Also `product` is allocated as a single word but used as 2 words. It's unclear what the code is doing, comment it especially if you want others to help. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Sure thing! I am typing in the radius as 7, and a the height of also 7 and its giving me the answer of 51.The answer should be 359.19.

Comment: If you have further information use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46333102/edit) link under the question to add it. Also note that this is integer code, you will never get an answer of `359.19`.

Comment: @jester I am returning now errors. I will comment the code right now so you can see. So how do I make it so it doesnt discard the result of mul radius?

Comment: Write it somewhere in memory, or transfer to another register that's not used.

Comment: And where is Pi? Bear in mind you need to work with floats here.

Comment: @yacc well that would be the `22/21`, approximating `pi/3` I guess.

Comment: @jester that is correct! (22/21 does approximate pi and yes this is integer code). I put it into another register and I am stilling coming up with the wrong answer.

Comment: Did you clear ah before setting al?

Comment: The updated code still doesn't put it anywhere. Also, both `radius` and `product` are unused (only written to). `mov height, dx` makes no sense either, `dx` is meaningless at that point (also contradicts your comment).

Comment: @Jester I cant seem to figure out how to mediate this in the code. I changed a few things on my end, however I am still coming up short.

Comment: You are mostly missing to learn how to use a debugger. Otherwise your code is pretty decent first version of something written in assembly, of course it doesn't work correctly, it never does (and when it sometimes does output expected output, it usually just means there's some subtle nasty bug hidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work better. Note you should choose where you want to widen the calculation to 64 bit.

```
askRadius       BYTE        "What is the radius?", 0ah, 0dh, 0              ;*** Declare the prompt and message parts
askHeight       BYTE        "What is the height? ", 0
volumeOutput    BYTE        "The volume of the cone is:  ", 0   
lineBreak       BYTE        " ",0dh, 0ah, 0

.code
main PROC

mov edx,OFFSET askRadius                 ;Asks for Radius
call WriteString
call ReadDec
imul eax, eax                            ; radius * radius
mov ecx, eax                             ; save for later

mov edx,OFFSET askHeight                 ;asks for Height
call writestring
call ReadDec
imul eax, eax, 22
mul ecx                                  ;multiplies by radius * radius
mov ecx, 21
div ecx                                  ;divides by 21

mov edx, OFFSET volumeOutput             
call WriteString
call WriteDec
call WaitMsg
exit

main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Why is it safe to assume that `ecx` survives two function calls?  Is that an Irvine32 thing?

Comment: In general it isn't, but here yes it's an Irvine32 thing. Might be worth pointing out.

Comment: Probably also good to explain the OP's specific mistake, which is that `div` takes the dividend from `edx:eax`.  (Of course there's already a canonical about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416593/why-should-edx-be-0-before-using-the-div-instruction/38416896#38416896).  I guess that was only one of the mistakes.