# Assembly crashes when trying to divide

Tags: assembly, x86

So, since dividing in assembly is a very hard topic i wanted to try it out.

```
1. mov eax, Winmine__XP.exe+579C // address of time elapsed
2. cmp [eax], 0x2                // compare time with 2
3. jge decrease                  // jump to decrease if time greater or equal 2
4. inc [eax]                        // increase deref eax
5. jmp exit                      // exit
6. decrease:
7. mov eax, [eax]                // deref eax into eax as dividend
8. mov ecx, 0x2                  // move 2 into ecx as divisor
9. div ecx                       // divide eax by ecx
// CRASH
```

Now i was wondering if my instruction of moving the dereferenced eax into eax crashes my program or if i was doing something wrong using division.

Comment: `inc [eax]` has ambiguous operand-size: a good assembler would refuse to assemble that without `inc dword [eax]` or similar, depending on which flavour of Intel syntax you're using.

Comment: If you want to divide by 2, use `shr eax,1`.  Or without loading first, `shr dword ptr [eax], 1`.  BTW, since you've apparently checked with a debugger that it doesn't crash until the actual `div` instruction, that rules out the load faulting on a bad address.

Comment: @PeterCordes alright, good to know but thats not the problem as the increase is working. It crashes when getting to [eax] = 2

Comment: I know, apparently whatever you used to assemble this has some default operand-size.  Hopefully dword!  That's why I just commented while looking for the canonical duplicate for failing to zero EDX.

Comment: Im compiling the asm using cheat engine

Comment: its working using `shr [eax],1` but thats not the goal of my project, im trying to use div.

Comment: Yeah, and that part is still a duplicate of [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416593).  I guess you didn't notice I already linked this question as a duplicate of that canonical Q&A a few minutes ago.

Comment: I just did right after i commented, moving 0 into edx fixes it. now imma go read why it works haha. thanks for your help

Comment: @Peter Cordes: `cmp [eax], 0x2` is missing a memory operand size too.