# Trying to Display a 32bit number in Assembly 8086 32bit

Tags: assembly, x86-16

**Task and Background:** For the past couple of week i've been learning assembly language, and as project i decided to build a 32bit calculator, that can multiplty, subtract, divide, and add numbers. I get as an input 2 16bit numbers (word, 2^16 -1 max), apply the mathmatical function on them, and then storing the answer in a 32bit variable (double word).

**The Problem and My Solution:** is that when trying to print the answer, i divide the number by 10 and push the remainder into the stack, and keep until the quotient is 0. But some times the quotient is bigger than the size of a word (2^16 -1). I can't manage to find a way around it.

**What I want it to do:** I want to divde the number (that is stored in the 32bit var) by 10, store the remainder into the stack, and store the quotient into a 32bit variable. Then looping this action until the quotinet is equal to zero.

**Currently:** I'm stuck, I am yet to find a way to divde two number without storing the quintent into ax.

```
print:
    mov dx, [word ptr answer+2]
    mov ax, [word ptr answer]

    mov     bx,10          ;CONST
    push    bx             ;Sentinel
    a: 
        div bx
        push dx
        xor dx,dx
        cmp ax,0
        JNE a
        ; first one in the stack one must be a digit
        pop dx
    b:  
        add dx, '0'
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h
        pop dx
        cmp dx, bx
        jne b
```

**P.s.**
I found this code that manages to print a 32bit number, but i can't fully understand How it works... If someone can explain me how it works?, and especially why does it divides (by 10) the top 16bits first and uses the reminder, in the division of the low 16bits. While learnig a new coding language I Have a rule, i can't use code from the web unless i fully understand it.

```
  mov     bx,10          ;CONST
    push    bx             ;Sentinel
.a: mov     cx,ax          ;Temporarily store LowDividend in CX
    mov     ax,dx          ;First divide the HighDividend
    xor     dx,dx          ;Setup for division DX:AX / BX
    div     bx             ; -> AX is HighQuotient, Remainder is re-used
    xchg    ax,cx          ;Temporarily move it to CX restoring LowDividend
    div     bx             ; -> AX is LowQuotient, Remainder DX=[0,9]
    push    dx             ;(1) Save remainder for now
    mov     dx,cx          ;Build true 32-bit quotient in DX:AX
    or      cx,ax          ;Is the true 32-bit quotient zero?
    jnz     .a             ;No, use as next dividend
    pop     dx             ;(1a) First pop (Is digit for sure)
.b: add     dl,"0"         ;Turn into character [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
    mov     ah,02h         ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h            ; -> AL
    pop     dx             ;(1b) All remaining pops
    cmp     dx,bx          ;Was it the sentinel?
    jb      .b             ;Not yet
```

[Original page of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos/45904076#45904076)

**Thanks**

Comment: [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416593) explains how to do extended-precision division with two `div` instructions.  e.g. in your case, 32-bit division on an 8086, thus no 32-bit registers.  [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075) includes an example of a 32-bit integer print.  (Oh, you did already find that; that's where your 2nd code block is from.)