# Why doesn't my Masm615/Win32 code output a result or an error to the console?

Tags: assembly, x86, console-application, masm, irvine32

i just learn this in a short semester like only 6 week. still confuse about the whole assembly language thing, this code is also used chatgpt to correct some error and this is the final version that the chatgpt gave me. still it have problem and i don't know where is the problem. The command prompt just blank after i run the code.

this is how it looks like  when i run the code
[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgSNO.png)

```
TITLE AssignmentP2 (Mult.asm)
; This program calculates the value using the following data
; Val1 = 340d
; Val2 = A3Ch
; Val3 = 45h
; FinalVal = -(Val1 – Val3) + 1 + (Val2 * 3) + 1 + 1 – 2 -1– (Val1 / 2)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE macros.inc  ; Include macros for WriteDec and Crlf

.data
Val1 dword 340d
Val2 dword 0A3Ch
Val3 dword 45h

.code
main proc
    mov eax, [Val1]  ; Load Val1 into eax
    sub eax, [Val3]  ; Subtract Val3 from eax
    neg eax          ; Negate eax (2's complement)
    inc eax          ; Add 1 to eax
    mov ebx, [Val2]  ; Load Val2 into ebx
    imul ebx, 3      ; Multiply ebx by 3
    add eax, ebx     ; Add ebx to eax
    inc eax          ; Add 1 to eax
    inc eax          ; Add 1 to eax
    sub eax, 2       ; Subtract 2 from eax
    dec eax          ; Subtract 1 from eax

    mov edx, eax     ; Preserve the result in edx
    mov ebx, [Val1]  ; Load Val1 into ebx
    mov ecx, 2       ; Divisor (2)
    div ecx          ; Divide eax by ecx (Val1 / 2)
    mov ecx, eax     ; Store the result (Val1 / 2) in ecx
    mov eax, edx     ; Restore the preserved result into eax

    call WriteDec    ; Call WriteDec to print the result

main endp

end main
```

the answe i expect in decimal is 12417.

Comment: It's not clear from your question which commands you ran to assemble and link your code.

Comment: When linking did you use `/subsystem:console` ? You are also missing `ret` at the end of `main`

Comment: The reason it doesn't print anything is likely because `DIV ECX` is actual EDX:EAX divided by ECX. EDX should be zeroed out before the DIV because EDX is part of the dividend and the calculation results in an integer overflow exception (that prematurely kills the program). Since EDX is part of the DIV calculation you will have to save the previous value in a register other than EDX (ie: ESI). You also are missing a subtraction at the end. I also believe the result should be 7419 (decimal). Note: Division by 2 can also be done by right shifting a value by 1 bit.

Comment: If that's the only bug, duplicate of [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416593) (except for the fact that powers of 2 should just use a shift.)

Comment: Integer math is associative, `1 + 1 + 1 - 2 - 1` is `0` so you can drop all the `inc`/`dec` instructions and the `sub eax,2` if you want.  Of course there are lots of other simplifications a compiler would make, too, like `-(x - y)` being `y-x`, and peephole optimizations like using `lea edx, [edx + edx*2]` to multiply by 3.  (Compilers would avoid EBX because it's call-reserved: if main returns to its caller, it has to restore the incoming value of EBX, or avoid using it.)  https://godbolt.org/z/xdh8cY5Tb shows GCC and MSVC's actual asm output, and unoptimized MSVC using `imul reg, mem, 3`

Comment: Assuming this is faulting with a divide exception, it's pretty bad that nothing is telling you about that.  If you wrote the same program under Linux, the shell would tell you your program exited with an arithmetic exception (it actually says "floating point exception", since POSIX requires `SIGFPE` if math is going to fault, even integer math, so things aren't perfect in terms of being easy to understand what problem to look for, but at least it's something to google on).  If you run this under a debugger, does it tell show you the problem?

Comment: @PeterCordes it is expected when the program has no exception handling. If he had run it in a debugger, the debugger would have caught the unhandled exceptions and shown the error.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Do other faults, like invalid page faults (bad pointers) or #GP (such as from misaligned SSE load/store) also just silently exit the program under Windows by default?  (At least for a console application?  I think I've seen screenshots of dialog boxes from invalid accesses.)  Yet another reason it's essential to use a debugger!

Comment: @PeterCordes : Yep, any program that doesn't catch exceptions will silently exit and the shell won't display anything. The code you see that displays an exception error usually is wrapped with exception handling (high level languages have the required code) and is being caught by the application. Console applications with proper exception handling will display useful error messages.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Can a better shell detect when a child process exited with an uncaught SEH(?) exception, e.g. Cygwin or MinGW bash, or in theory if those don't?

Comment: The MinGW shell running the windows program in this example doesn't display unhandled exceptions. Windows PowerShell doesn't either.

Comment: I actually get it right after I see @PeterCordes comment as it really helps a lot even though it still takes some time on Youtube and Google to understand the concept but I eventually get it. Thanks a lot 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After my last answer (which was not so good) I decided to return to idea from first post. Calculations + output. Prints 7419.

```
TITLE AssignmentP2 (Mult.asm)
; This program calculates the value using the following data
; Val1 = 340d
; Val2 = A3Ch
; Val3 = 45h
; FinalVal = -(Val1 – Val3) + 1 + (Val2 * 3) + 1 + 1 – 2 -1– (Val1 / 2)
                    
include \masm32\include\Irvine32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\Irvine32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib


.data
Val1 dword 340d  
Val2 dword 0A3Ch  ; 2620       
Val3 dword 45h    ; 69             

.code
main proc
    mov eax, [Val1]  ; Load Val1 into eax
  
    sub eax, [Val3]  ; Subtract Val3 from eax
    
    neg eax          ; Negate eax (2's complement)
    
    inc eax          ; Add 1 to eax
    
    mov ebx, [Val2]  ; Load Val2 into ebx
    
    imul ebx, 3      ; Multiply ebx by 3

    add eax, ebx     ; Add ebx to eax

    inc eax          ; Add 1 to eax
    
    inc eax          ; Add 1 to eax

    sub eax, 2       ; Subtract 2 from eax
    
    dec eax          ; Subtract 1 from eax

    mov ebx, [Val1]  ; Load Val1 into ebx

    shr ebx, 1       ; divide value in ebx by 2
   
    sub eax, ebx     ; Substract value in ebx from eax                      

    call WriteDec
    exit
    ret
main endp

end main
```

Comment: What specifically does this code do that fixes the problem(s) from the question? Why is this code roughly 4 times as large as the code in the question?

Comment: Nothing special, just calculates step by step this equation and shows in console window result of every instruction. Lines `mov [show_reg], X`, `call output` can be easily removed and `output proc` as well. After all calculations `WriteInt` is enough because I think `WriteDec` doesn't work well with negative numbers.

Comment: A huge code block is going to be really slow reading especially for beginners, especially without any text pointing out what kind of changes you made.  There isn't even a comment on the key change, `shr ebx, 1`.  Good answers should have text that answers the question of what was wrong with the code, and explaining what the code block is showing.

Comment: Also, the OP is expecting a positive result.  Copy/pasting the original expression into `calc` with `Val1=340` / `Val2=0xA3C` / `Val3 = 0x45`, I get 7419, which is different from both your result and the result they expected. :/  The expression in the comment (with non-ASCII `-` signs fixed) is `-(Val1 - Val3) + 1 + (Val2 * 3) + 1 + 1 - 2 -1 - (Val1 / 2)`

Comment: `Val1` is 340d or OP just typed fast and instead of `d` should be `h`? `340h`?

Comment: I changed value to `340h` and result is `6681`. And expression is `-(Val1 - Val3) + 1 + (Val2 * 3) + 1 + 1 - 2 - 1 - (Val1 / 2)`?

Comment: Ok if `val1` is 340 result is`7419`, my code shows good result.

Comment: I assumed `340d` was intentionally specifying decimal, because a `d` suffix for that is valid MASM syntax.  (Confusingly, since it looks like someone forgot a trailing h when trying to write `340Dh`, but I've seen plenty of people write decimal numbers "explicitly" that way in previous SO questions.)  The mathematical result with `Val2=0x340D` is `-12058.5`, not an integer, so that's another reason to doubt it was intended.  I haven't tried to figure out what inputs would give the OP's "expected" result.

Comment: BTW, see recent meta discussion about code-only answers that don't explain themselves: [How can we encourage answers that are helpful to people other than the asker?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426696) - it's widely agreed that explanations are much better for anyone who stumbles over the Q&A later (including people looking for duplicates for future Qs), as well as for the OP.  There is valid debate over whether it's better to post just code vs. not answering at all if you don't have time to write even a sentence or two about the code you're posting.

Comment: Perhaps you could preface this answer by saying "I played around with this some out of my own curiosity", because that's what this looks like.  If you just wanted to see values change as you go through the steps, use a debugger that highlights the last register(s) to change as you single-step.  That's why we have debuggers, because as your answer shows, writing debug-prints in asm takes way more code than in C where you can just slap a printf somewhere without disturbing other variables.  (Irvine32 does have `call DumpReg`, but that won't highlight the last change.)

Comment: Now your answer has some text, but you still don't mention the primary problem with the code in the question (which is what was stopping it from printing an answer at all): [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416593) . That was only mentioning comments, no actual answers.  For someone who doesn't already know that, they'd have to read through your answer 1 line at a time to compare it with the question and find the difference(s) to see what they are.